# Is there any Markdown syntax parser for JavaScript with table?

Tags: javascript, parsing, markdown, multimarkdown

I am looking for a Markdown syntax JavaScript parser with the table feature. It seems that I cant find one so I am having the hassle of implementing this feature into existing code, but I am not being able to do so. Does anyone know a JavaScript library that parses [MULTIMARKDOWN](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) or at least a not so difficult way to implement the table feature?

By table feature I mean a syntax to be transformed in an HTML table, for example:

```
|= header1 |= hader2
| cell 1 | cell 2
```

would become

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
             header1
        </th>
        <th>
             header2
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             cell1
        </td>
        <td>
             cell2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So far I have even tried mixing a Wiki parser with Markdown parser with no success.

**EDIT: I need it to run on the browser not for node.js**

Comment: What troubles are you having making it yourself? Seems like it is a split and looping.

Comment: I tried implementing the the table parser myself - modifing the string before sending to showdown: I could parse the table but everytime got caught in syntax exceptions that was difficult to handle - I tried sending the string first to a wiki parser that has this feature, but It messed up the rest of the string so showdown couldnt parse it correctly - would have any suggestion on how to solve this???

Answer (score 2):

I have an implementation of GitHub table syntax at [ghw](https://github.com/bebraw/ghw/blob/master/lib/ghw.js). Feel free to use that if you want. Note that it depends on [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked).

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Apparently marked should work in browser too. Here's another attempt at table syntax btw: https://github.com/chjj/marked/pull/74 .

Comment: Good to know that! I'll need a markdown parser that runs in the browser for adding 'live markdown editor' (like mouapp for Mac OS X) to my LIVEditor (http://liveditor.com)

Comment: marked should work in browsers. It supports GitHub table syntax these days even.

Answer (score 1):

[Showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) which is a JavaScript port of Markdown, and use the [table extension](https://github.com/showdownjs/table-extension).

I ran into a problem with loading the table plugin: `Uncaught Extension 'undefined' could not be loaded. It was either not found or is not a valid extension.` this can be fixed by loading the extension this way: `var converter = new showdown.Converter({ extensions: ['table'] });` as pointed [out here](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown/pull/64).

There is another bug if you have multiple tables on the one document it repeats them, the fix for that is [here](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown/pull/48/files).

Comment: The multiple tables bug has been fixed a while ago